# Redirect Rule for .aspx to terminated slash?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I've got an existing rule:

```
<rewrite url="~/([^-]+)(?:-(.+))?/(.+).aspx" to="~/Results.aspx?city=$1&amp;state=$2&amp;term=$3&amp;x=$4"/>
```

Which I would like to replace with a non .aspx extension and trailing slash.

Thus, the url would be something like www.mysite.com/City-State/My-Search-Term/ which redirects to Results.aspx that reads the rewritten querystring.

I'm moving from a .net rewrite solution (thus the requirement for the .aspx extension) to the URL Rewrite on IIS 7.

As I'm still not entirely familiar with the syntax, this is what I was thinking... which isn't quite working:

```
    <rule name="Redirect .aspx to " enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="~/([^-]+)(?:-(.+))?/(.+)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="~/Results.aspx?city={R:0}&amp;state={R:1}&amp;term={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Also for cached search engine links, I need to write a rule that retains the .aspx rule above, redirecting it using the new URL structure - no .aspx and a trailing slash.

I'm rewriting this particular app using MVC3.  I'm familiar with the slash structure with MVC, but just want to make sure that these rules will apply to the new architecture as well.

Lastly, I also require a rule that doesn't use the /City-State/ portion, and doesn't mess up my ~/Images/*.*,  ~/Scripts/*.* and ~/Styles/*.* references.

Thanks.